# Twitter crashes after Tweet

Tags: twitter, ionic2

I'm using:

```
window.open(`twitter://post?text=${caption}`, "_system");
```

to post tweets from my Ionic 2 app.

This successfully opens the app and creates the tweet.
After the post the twitter just crashes and my app crashes too.

I could get this log from Android Studio:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1d9cr6htug4ai6/Screenshot%202017-01-26%2018.05.09.png?dl=0

This happens both with Android and iOS phones.

Anyone has seen this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use InAppBrowser ?

```
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';
...
let browser = new InAppBrowser('https://ionic.io', '_system');
```

But the better solution you want is ionic built in social sharing plugin

```
import { SocialSharing } from 'ionic-native';

// Check if sharing via email is supported
SocialSharing.canShareViaEmail().then(() => {
  // Sharing via email is possible
}).catch(() => {
  // Sharing via email is not possible
});

// Share via email
SocialSharing.shareViaTwitter(message, image, url).then(() => {
  // Success!
}).catch(() => {
  // Error!
});
```